# Custom task type not found when importing Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am facing the following conundrum for which I spent a great deal of time trying to resolve with no success so far. I have a custom Gradle plugin whose job is to start a process and run it in the background.

My code plugin code is the following:

```
public class TaskSpawnerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('spawnTask', type: TaskSpawner)
    }

}
```

And this is the task in question:

```
public class TaskSpawner extends DefaultTask {

    @Input
    String command

    @Input
    String ready

    @Input
    String workDir = '.'

    TaskSpawner() {
        description = 'Given a Unix like cmd, this will start it and let it run on the background'
    }

    @TaskAction
    public void spawn() {
        getLogger().quiet "Attempting to run provided command $command"
        if (!(command && ready)) {
            throw new GradleException("Please make sure that both the command and ready check are provided!")
        }
        waitFor(createProcess(workDir, command))
    }

    private def waitFor(Process process) {
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())).withCloseable {
            reader ->
                def line
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    getLogger().quiet line
                    if (line.contains(ready)) {
                        getLogger().quiet "$command is ready"
                        break
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private def static createProcess(String directory, String command) {
        new ProcessBuilder(command.split(' '))
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .directory(Paths.get(directory).toFile())
                .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .start()
    }

}
```

The code resides under a package structure that has following package name

`fts.gradle`

My build script looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group =  'fts.gradle'
version = '0.3'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        greetingsPlugin  {
            id = 'fts.gradle.taskspawn'
            implementationClass = 'fts.gradle.TaskSpawnerPlugin'
        }
    }
}
```

I build my plugin normally and deploy it on a locally hosted artifactory. My problem revolves around how to import it and use it in a project.

For the time being I do the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "<maven_url>" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'fts.gradle', name: 'task-spawner', version: '0.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'eclipse'
}

apply plugin: 'fts.gradle'
```

And then I attempt to apply it using the following:

But when attempting to refresh the project this action fails:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':integration-tests'.
> Could not get unknown property 'TaskSpawner' for project ':integration-tests' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I have read the documentation and I have tried all the various ways of creating and importing a plugin as a standalone jar but so far I've unsuccessful.

Can anyone please shed some light here? This has been driving nuts for the past days.

Note, for reference the Gradle version I use it 5.6.2

Comment: Do you try to create a task of that type in your build script and that causes the failure?

Comment: When I explicitly include the code within the build script it works fine. My problem is when I extract the code, place it in another project and attempt to include the plugin as an externally fetched plugin

Comment: Could you add the part of your `build.gradle` file where the plugin is applied / used?

Comment: @LukasKörfer I have updated the question with the information you requested.